# Windows 8.1 - Start menu appears instead of desktop during startup

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, desktop, startmenu

once I had installed [Start Menu 8](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iobit.com%2Fen%2Fiobitstartmenu8.php&ei=60uWVemwMoy8uATIi4LAAg&usg=AFQjCNEBXhm33dnLgttoeKkq_yPGeFcdMQ&sig2=baPWOkSd4bP3KuEakqI_5g) . After one day I uninstalled it because I didn't like that. But after uninstalling, I am facing a problem in Win 8.1. When I log in, then first start menu appears and then I have to open desktop manually. But I want desktop to appear at startup. Is there any manual settings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To boot to the desktop instead of Start
>   Open Taskbar and Navigation properties by swiping in from the right edge of the screen, tapping Search (or if you're using a mouse, pointing to the upper-right corner of the screen, moving the mouse pointer down, and then clicking Search), entering Taskbar in the search box, and then tapping or clicking Taskbar and Navigation in the results.
>
> Tap or click the Navigation tab, then tap or click the When I sign in or close all apps on a screen, go to the desktop instead of Start check box. Then tap or click OK.

Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/personalize-pc-tutorial

Please use search engines like Google in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on taskbar and open `properties`. Select `Navigation` tab and check the option `Show Start on the display I’m using when I press the Windows logo key`.

Press OK and reboot to try it out.